# Importing C file with python bindings in python file

Tags: python, c, import, binding

There is a great program written in C, that also contains a conversion to python using python bindings. However I would like to extend the file with bindings to give it more functionality.

When I try to change 'import bounded_file' to 'import my_bounded_file' in the python file the bindings are used in, I get a file not found error. So my question is how do I import a .c file into a .py program if the .c file contains python bindings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The C file needs to be compiled to a shared library. Then, you import this library.